# External display remains on after closing lid even without peripherals

Tags: display, sleep-wake

I don’t have a mouse or keyboard connnected so I don’t think I should be entering clamshell mode.

When I shut the lid of the laptop, the display remains on and doesn’t lock either. Reopening the lid of the laptop doesn’t ask me for a password either, even though I have the setting to ask for password immediately on. Eventually it starts the screensaver but that’s it.

When I’m not plugged into power, everything works as expected.

This happens in safe mode too, pmset logs aren’t really helping either.

I’m on macOS Sonoma beta.

Comment: The hardware component that detects when the lid is closed may be broken.

Answer (score 0):

You must have accidentally changed the sleep settings. Run the command `sudo pmset -b sleep 0; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 0` to fix it and enter your password where needed.

Comment: No change :( I think reinstalling macOS might be my only option.